# -use-intel-optimized-headers not recognized ("argument unused during compilation") for compilation, only for linking?

Tags: intel, valarray, icpx

Trying to follow this (Intel64/Linux):

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/libraries/intel-c-class-libraries/intel-s-valarray-implementation.html

But it doesn't seem to recognize -use-intel-optimized-headers for compilation, only for linking?

icpx -use-intel-optimized-headers -c valarray.C

icpx: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-u se-intel-optimized-headers' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

icpx -use-intel-optimized-headers valarray.o

(no error/warning)

icpx -use-intel-optimized-headers valarray.C

(no error/warning)

(FWIW, icpc doesn't seem to produce the same error message)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The intel website seems to imply that the -use-intel-optimized-headers flag should be use both for compiling and linking.  But it’s complaining it doesn’t recognize this option when compiling (when using icpx; icpc seems ok)

Comment: We could reproduce your issue. We are working on this internally and will update once resolved. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. With the transition from icc/icpc to llvm-based icx/icpx, we improved compiler diagnostics which are now inline with clang.

Given the option "-use-intel-optimized-headers" is only used at link time and not compile time, icpx producing the warning of it being unused in a compile-only step is expected.

Thanks,
Varsha